# nginx: Serve file.css.xgz with the right headers

Tags: nginx, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

I have a stylesheet gzip compressed on disk and would like to serve it via nginx. It's named `file.css.xgz` and it should have

```
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Compression: gzip
```

So I added this to `mime.types`:

```
text/css                              css css.xgz;
```

And this to my `server` configuration:

```
location ~* \.xgz$ {
  add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
}
```

Server is restarted for sure, but the content-type is still `application/octet-stream` (Content-Encoding is set as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Try just "xgz" in the mime type in place of "css.xgz"